# Pandas: How can I concatenate 2 columns as a multiline string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to concatenate them using multiline string. Below is my pandas dataframe,

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,"This is the desc of id 1"],[4,"This is the desc of id 2"]], columns=["id","desc"])
```

I wanted string like below,

```
functionalRequirement 1{{
  id: 1
  text: This is the desc of id 1
  risk: high
  verifymethod: test
}}
```

I tried below code but it didnt work.

```
df['res'] = f"""
functionaRequirement {df['id']} {{
    id: {df['id']}
    text: {df['desc']}
    risk: high
    verifymethod: test
}} 
"""
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string formatting and apply it over all rows

```py
fstring = """functionaRequirement {id} {{
     id: {id}
     text: {desc}
     risk: high
     verifymethod: test
 }}"""

df["res"] = df.apply(lambda r: fstring.format(id=r.id, desc=r.desc), axis=1)

>>> print(df.res[0])
functionaRequirement 1 {
    id: 1
    text: This is the desc of id 1
    risk: high
    verifymethod: test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
df['res'] = [f"""
functionaRequirement {id} {{
    id: {id}
    text: {desc}
    risk: high
    verifymethod: test
}} 
""" for id, desc in zip(df['id'], df['desc'])]
```

Or if performance matters:

```
ID = df['id'].astype(str)
df['res'] = '\nfunctionaRequirement '+ID+' {\n    id: '+ID+'\n    text: '+df['desc']+'\n    risk: high\n    verifymethod: test\n}'
```

Output:

```
   id                      desc                                                                                                                      res
0   1  This is the desc of id 1  \nfunctionaRequirement 1 {\n    id: 1\n    text: This is the desc of id 1\n    risk: high\n    verifymethod: test\n} \n
1   4  This is the desc of id 2  \nfunctionaRequirement 4 {\n    id: 4\n    text: This is the desc of id 2\n    risk: high\n    verifymethod: test\n} \n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) template withT [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to export your dataframe as dict:

```
import string

TEMPLATE = string.Template("""\
functionaRequirement ${id} {{
    id: ${id}
    text: ${desc}
    risk: high
    verifymethod: test
}}""")

df['res'] = list(map(TEMPLATE.substitute, df.to_dict('records')))
# OR
df['res'] = [TEMPLATE.substitute(rec) for rec in df.to_dict('records')]
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id                      desc                                                res
0   1  This is the desc of id 1  functionaRequirement 1 {{\n    id: 1\n    text...
1   4  This is the desc of id 2  functionaRequirement 4 {{\n    id: 4\n    text...

>>> print(df.loc[0, 'res'])
functionaRequirement 1 {{
    id: 1
    text: This is the desc of id 1
    risk: high
    verifymethod: test
}}
```